# Scrolling pixel-by-pixel with direction pad in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, scrolling, pixels

Is there a configuration setting in Firefox that allows me to control using the arrow keys to scroll into a direction by 1 pixel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign 1 px scrolling to `Alt+mousewheel`, just open `about:config` and change the `mousewheel.withaltkey.action` value to `4`. `4` means `Scroll the document by a number of pixels`. Make sure the `mousewheel.withaltkey.sysnumlines` is set to `false` and `mousewheel.withaltkey.numlines` is `1`.

Now you can scroll by one pixel by holding the `Alt` when using the mousewheel.

[Here](http://xahlee.info/mswin/Firefox_mouse_wheel_scroll_speed.html) you can find some more details.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working today. There are no `mousewheel.withaltkey.(sys)numlines` config properties.

Comment: @Victor: Indeed, scrolling by pixel appears to be [unsupported since Firefox 17](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Mouse_Wheel_Scrolling#Mozilla_17_.28Firefox_17.29_or_later).

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could find to what you want is to set the number of pixels which are scrolled by the *mousewheel*.

In case it's useful:

In `about:config` look for `mousewheel.withnokey.action` and set it (or create an integer value) to `4`. Then find `mousewheel.withnokey.numlines` and set it to `1` (which is 1 pixel.)

Comment: Great, thanks for that but I'm hoping this can be done to the directional pad only (which is still skipping) as I just also realized how  much I use the mousewheel for scrolling, so keeping that setting on would be a real headache.